# Pass param with .& operator to a static method

Tags: groovy, static-methods

With groovy [`.&` operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#method-pointer-operator) one can create references to static methods, as in

```
def static xyz( name='Joe' ) {
 println "Hello ${name}"
}

// NOTE: ConsoleScript number part varies
def ref = ConsoleScript52.&xyz
```

And can be easilly called without params, as

```
ref()  // prints "Hello "
```

But how can this method be called with params? `ref('John')` gives an error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript52.xyz() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [John]`

Note that Groovy does not even use the default value of name param in above example when static method is called with ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a `ConsoleScript` instance where you did not define that method with parameters.

In the code below, in the *8th* execution in my console (`ConsoleScript8`) y defined the method `hello()` without parameters (added the *"script number"* to make it explicit):

```
println this.getClass().getName()
println ''

def static hello() {
    println "(8) Hello"
}

def h8 = ConsoleScript8.&hello
h8()
h8('Joe')
```

And it yields the following in the next execution:

```
ConsoleScript9

(8) Hello
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript9.hello() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Joe]
```

And in the *10th* execution (`ConsoleScript10`) I modified it adding the default parameter:

```
println this.getClass().getName()
println ''

def static hello(name='amigo') {
    println "(10) Hello ${name}"
}

def h10 = ConsoleScript10.&hello
h10()
h10('Joe')

println '--'

def h8 = ConsoleScript8.&hello
h8()
h8('Joe')
```

And it yields:

```
ConsoleScript12

(10) Hello amigo
(10) Hello Joe
--
(8) Hello
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript8.hello() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Joe]
```

It is easier if you use an explicit class:

```
class Greeter {
    def static hello(name='Joe') {
        "Hello ${name}"
    }
}

def hi = Greeter.&hello
assert hi() == 'Hello Joe'
assert hi('Tom') == 'Hello Tom'
```

Comment: You are correct, the problem was solved by using an explicit class.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Groovy?  This works with Groovy 2.4.5:

```
class Test {
    static greet(name = 'tim') {
        "Hello ${name.capitalize()}"
    }
}

// regular static calls
assert Test.greet()             == 'Hello Tim'
assert Test.greet('kaskelotti') == 'Hello Kaskelotti'

// Create a reference to the static method
def ref = Test.&greet

// Calling the reference works as well
assert ref()             == 'Hello Tim'
assert ref('kaskelotti') == 'Hello Kaskelotti'
```

Comment: Sorry Tim, you were equally right as @jalopaba above, but just a bit slower :). The problem occurs when the static method is defined directly instead of having it part of a class as in your example.

Comment: And the groovy console states that it's version 2.4.5

Comment: @kaskelotti I was actually quicker by about 2 minutes :-) glad it's sorted though